# How to fix ValueError: too many values to unpack?? PYTHON

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm

```
lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True,return_state=True)

bilstm1,state_h1,state_c1 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm_layer, name="BiLSTM1", merge_mode="concat")(reshape)
bilstm2,state_h2,state_c2 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm_layer, name="BiLSTM2", merge_mode='concat')(bilstm1)
```

But

```
bilstm1,state_h1,state_c1 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm_layer, name="BiLSTM1", merge_mode="concat")(reshape)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the first 3 items, and want to ignore the rest, you could probably do:

```py
bilstm1, state_h1, state_c1, *_ = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm_layer, name="BiLSTM1", merge_mode="concat")(reshape)
```

Most likely, other lines would need such changes, too.

Needless to say that if the right operand unpacks in less than 3 items, you'll still get an error.